# C# and delete specific row in SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

My problem is I don't get any errors, but when I tried to delete specific data from the database, the system would just display `Data Deleted`.

```
private void Delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string Query = "delete from dbo.student where C_ID=" + textBox1.Text;
    cc.con = new SqlConnection(cs.DBConn);
    cc.con.Open();

    try
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Data Deleted");
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("User Not Deleted");
    }
}
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: Also - you're just establishing a connection - but you're never actually **executing** that query....

Comment: I will not help you to fix your existing code but ask you to change to use `SqlParamter` and it will resolve your problem. Fixing existing code does not help resolve `injection attack` problem

Comment: thanks everyone. before this ive used parameter but there are some errors and i deleted it and let it empty like code above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to actually create a `SqlCommand` and **execute** the query! Also - to avoid SQL injection and other problems, please ***always*** use parametrized queries!

Try something like this:

```
private void Delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string delQuery = "DELETE FROM dbo.student WHERE C_ID = @ID";

    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cs.DBConn))
        using (SqlCommand cmdDel = new SqlCommand(delQuery, conn))
        {
            // define parameter and set value
            cmdDel.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);

            // open connection, execute query, close connection
            conn.Open();
            int rowsDeleted = cmdDel.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();

            // show success message
            MessageBox.Show("Data Deleted");
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("User Not Deleted");
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks sir.  before this ive used parameter but there are some errors and i deleted it and let it empty like code above. now i need to make some changes because when i enter non existing numbers then it still appeared "Data Deleted" . for example i enter 1 but in db there are no ID 1 so it sill appeared "Data Deleted". anyway thanks for helping me sir

Comment: @MuhammadAshraf Guess what you can do with the information stored in rowsDeleted variable. If the id exist then you should expect the value 1 and if not then you should expect 0 rows that were deleted ;o)

Comment: @SirRufo yes ive solved by set the value. thanks sir